# Web Socket between C# Console Application and a browser

Tags: c#, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

Is it possible (and simple) for C# console to open a web socket with a browser, without using Node.js? Meaning, an active and opened C# console application, always running on the server, which can send and receive messages to and from the browser at real time.

I tried to use a browser loading the socket.io.js JS file (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.4/socket.io.js), and creating a C# console application using TcpListener class. And there seems to be a successful connection. But I can't send messages between the server and the client.

Comment: Yes it is possible, but use dedicated websocket library and not raw TcpListener.

Comment: Yes it is, you can use [RedHttpServer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RHttpServer/) or SignalR as mentioned by programmerj. There are many different libraries for this, so use one of those instead of the TcpListener class, since you will then have to implement the WebSocket procotol on top of it yourself.

Comment: Side-note: reading your question it seems as if you're trying to have the C# application open a connection to the browser. This is impossible because Websockets require that the browser open the connection to the server. Your C# application can definitely listen to Websocket connections, but it can't initiate them. I'm sure this is what you actually meant, but the way you wrote your question is slightly confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I've done it several times.

C# console / Windows service:  Use SignalR library.  Should be able to get it via NuGet.

Web application: Use jquery.signalr-x.x.x.js library.

SignalR should primarily establish a WebSocket connection between the SignalR hub in our .NET app, and the jquery.signalr client library in your web application.